# Building conda package with C++ extensions fails to find headers

Tags: python, c++, shared-libraries, fftw, conda-build

I am building locally a conda package. I have reduced its structure to the MWE below:

```bash
.
├── build.sh
├── cythonwrap.pyx
├── pythonmodule.py
├── lib
│   ├── function.cpp
│   └── header.h
├── meta.yml
└── setup.py
```

`function.cpp` requires shared libraries headers (fftw3.h).
I am building the conda package locally in a fresh conda environment.

Conda ships compilers as metapackages (`cxx-compiler` for `g++`) and shared libraries (e.g. `gsl` and `fftw3`) to avoid dependencies on the host environment where the package is built.

This are installed and available in the host environment, with link and headers in
the conda environment `./lib` and `./include/` folders.

Nonetheless, when building the package it stops because it could not locate the `fftw3.h` header. Could someone provide a mw `meta.yaml` recipe for this kind of situation?

Here is the one that doesn't work:

```yaml
package:
  name: mypackage
  version: 0.0

source:
  path: ./

build:
  number: 0
  preserve_egg_dir: True

requirements:
  build:
    - python
    - {{ compiler('cxx') }}  # This will automatically include the C++ compiler
    - Cython
    - numpy
  host:
    - Cython
    - python
    - fftw
  run:
    - python
    - Cython

about:
  home: ...
  license: ...
  summary: "..."
  description: "..."
  dev_url: http://myurl
  doc_source_url: ...
```